# launch a .bat in TFS2015 build

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have a problem trying to launch a server via a .bat file during a TFS build.
I usually launch the server via a cmd window and it works fine.
When I set it in the TFS build, I end up with the following message :

```
"'..\server_common.bat' is not recognized as an internal command or external, an executable or a command file".
```

I also have the following line:

```
"java   -Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true  -Xbootclasspath/a:..\..\..\lib\framework\serverjvm15.jar; -cp ..\..\..\lib\framework\fwtime.jar;" indicating a java syntax error (? I'm not skilled in java)
```

This batch calls other .bat files and sets java VM-related environment variables

From my research, it is probably a problem of rights as I don't have admin rights when I use TFS. However, all the other steps in the build work fine (installing and launching an appli through command lines, or launching a python script via command lines).

However I also tried to launch a basic script with the same kind of step and it works.

Comment: Share your Run Batch File or Run Command Line build step parameters. You're probably incorrectly specifying the relative path to the batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, suggest you to follow the tutorial in [**Batch script**](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/batch-script). Make sure you have meet the requirements of Arguments and used correctly.  Such as

> **Path**
>
> Specify the path to the .bat or .cmd script you want to run. The path
>   must be **a fully qualified path or a valid path** relative to
>   the default working directory. In Team Foundation Build, this
>   directory is `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`.

Also RDP to your build agent and use your build service account manually run the `server_common.bat` to narrow down if the account have enough permission.

Comment: actually, when I launch the .bat file, it works, if I launch it through command line, it fails. I modified the relative paths inside the scripts, as suggested by Daniel and it seems to work much better, though I end up being stuck in the process as I didn't launch it in background ... (I'm currently trying to solve this out)

Comment: @A.Joly You can use built-in variable for the relative path, such as $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\.....

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT thanks for your help, but when I launch my batch, that launches a server in background, I expect a new window to open but it's not the case. The process starts but it's killed as soon as TFS switches to the next step ... I set the working directory to be the same in the two steps, as I thought it could be the problem but there's something else ... do you have any idea ?

Comment: Hi @A.joly Did you have any related log info for troubleshooting?  You could also enable `system.debug=ture` enable Verbose Debug Mode for vNext build

Comment: Actually, the only log I have concerns the steps after the server launching. The only info I have in the running script log is :  Error message highlight pattern: with nothing behind and Warning message highlight pattern: with nothing behind. I always have these traces, even when I do the (successful) process without launching the server by a TFS step

Comment: I'm not familiar with debug under windows, how do you implement the system.debug=ture bit ? in the .bat file it doesn't work ...

Comment: @A.Joly This a variable setting in tfs build definition, more detail steps please refer this tutorial: https://www.benday.com/2016/09/19/enable-verbose-debug-mode-for-tfs-build-vnext/

Comment: Awesome ! :)  however it is not much more verbose on the faulty step. The only information (not even new) is a "finalization task : BatchScript". It seems to me that the batch is properly executed, but then the process is killed by something else. Can this finalization task kill the background process launched by the batch script ?

Comment: I may try to launch the server in a build then, from this build launch another build that carries all the other steps, but I'm not sure it'll work